# What is causing the visual glitch in my hta file

Tags: vbscript, hta

I am currently working on a program that displays a photo, however, it causes a visual glitch that causes the photo to shift down and a bit to the right. I have included the code and a screen shot. The glitch shifts the photo and adds a white border to the top and left sides of the hta windows. Is this an error in the code? The extra bit of VBScript is to shutdown the photo after 60 seconds. If that is the cause of the error, please let me know, but I have tested it a few other times without the embedded VBScript.

[image: Screnshot]

```html
<html>
    <hta:application id="oHTA"
        scroll="no"
        scrollFlat="no"
        selection="no"
    />
    <script language="VBScript">
        Sub Window_OnLoad
            ' Resize and position the window
            width = 400 : height = 400
            window.resizeTo width, height
            window.moveTo screen.availWidth\2 - width\2, screen.availHeight\2 - height\2

            ' Automatically close the windows after 5 seconds
            idTimer = window.setTimeout("vbscript:window.close", 60000)
        End Sub
    </script>
<body>
    <table border=0 width="100%" height="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">
                <img src="C:\Users\Syd\Desktop\delta.jpg"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px">` works for me. I'm going to delete my answer if you say that _it shifted the image even more down_.

Comment: might as well delete it then, because it is not the answer for my problem

Comment: The solution JosefZ proposed resolves the issue when I tested it with your sample code. You need to provide more information if it doesn't work for you.